# ASP.NET Web Site + SQL Backed Session

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, vs-web-site-project

We are using an ASP.NET web site project with dynamic compilation, and recently moved to a SQL Server backed session state and started getting a strange error.  I've figured out what is causing this, but I don't know the best way to resolve it.

Steps to reproduce on localhost (with sql session enabled):

- Place an object defined in AppCode, lets say it's a `DanObject` into the session.

  Session["x"] = new DanObject();
- (Session is serialized to the database)
- Modify something in app code, causing the site to recompile on the next request
- Make a request to any page that accesses the session

The error is "Unable to find assembly 'App_SubCode_CS.rmdbqb81, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

What's happening is that every time AppCode is compiled, it goes into a randomly named assembly. When my Session is serialized the first time, AppCode happened to be named AppCode_123.  When I modified my application, AppCode is now AppCode_456.  However the Session stored in my database has an object defined in AppCode_123.  When the Session tries to binary deserialize the DanObject, it blows up because it can't find AppCode_123.

What is the simplest way I can fix this?
*Please don't say switch to Web Application--our code base is huge and it is not feasible at this point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was we had separate folders in `App_Code` for different code languages. This is why in the error message, it said "App_SubCode_CS..." instead of "App_Code...", because the specific class came from a CS code folder (for c# code). Each of these code folders (defined in web.config) get compiled into its own assembly.

Normally when you don't have multiple code folders AppCode, ASP.NET is able to serialize and deserialize objects compiled at different times or on different servers because the assembly name ("AppCode.randomstring") is stored with the class name in the serialized output. On deserialization, the framework calls `System.Type.GetType()` on the assembly + class name, and that function has a special case to handle assembly names starting with `App_Code`, where if it doesn't find an assembly named exactly the same, but it does find one that starts with App_Code, it uses that assembly to load the class.

When you have language folders in `App_Code`, the generated assemblies are named like: `App_SubCode_FOLDERNAME.randomstring`, and the framework doesn't seem to handle this case.  So if you have 2 webservers sharing a Sql backed session, class Foo is compiled as `"App_SubCode_FN.random1, Foo"` on server A, and `"App_SubCode_FN.random2, Foo"` on server B.  If a user gets a Foo in his session from server A, and then his next request goes to server B, server B will be unable to deserialize the Foo because it can't find an assembly named `"App_SubCode_FN.random1"`.

The problem can be solved by getting rid of your old VB code (allowing app code to be compiled into a single assembly that .NET plays more nicely with), or by writing a custom SerializationBinder + a custom implementation of the Sql Server backed session.

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit namespace around DanObject

Comment: +1: By far the easiest fix for a huge app. Of course, I'd recommend not storing full objects in session anyway, but it sounds like this project is already a performance nightmare so it probably just doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: @Chris Lively exactly, I had started writing about moving into separate library and looking at what you are serializing, but think I'll KISS for now, answer-wise.

Comment: This didn't work. I think the BinarySerializer is using the AssemblyQualifiedName, which includes the random name on AppCode

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, second easiest solution:**
Move the code for this class instead a separate assembly library.  This way when the serializer sees the class it will have a known good name to work from.  Of course, this removes your ability to make edits directly to the app_code directory... which you shouldn't be doing anyway.

**Third easiest (and the best one) solution:**
Don't put objects into session.  If there are a couple properties you need, that's one thing, store those properties as regular strings.

```
<slight_rant>
```

Seriously, putting full objects into session is NOT what it was built for.

See my answer here ( [Sessions and storing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490583/sessions-and-storing-objects/4490645#4490645) ) for a little more information on the reasons why you don't want to do this.

And, onto the final note: This problem seems to only be an issue because you guys are persisting session AND making changes directly to the code on the web server.  Stop doing that.  Make your changes (and test them) locally, then precompile and deploy your site, finally invalidate session once it's deployed.  Do this on a normallized release schedule so everyone knows when the downtime is.

```
</slight_rant>
```

Comment: we don't edit app code directly on the server. We have multiple servers on a load balancer and we want to be able to push code mid-day without taking the entire site down... So we take a server out of the rotation, push new code to it, and then put it back in the rotation.  The problem is that the objects serialized from AppCode blow up.